# How do I make these two web.config transforms to work?

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, web.config-transform

I created a configuration named **Local** and I want my `web.local.config` to be transformed thus:

**1. Connection String**

My `web.config` has the following connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" 
         connectionString = "dummy"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I would like my `web.local.config` to have the following, though:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Entities"
     connectionString="What a nice connection string!"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have presently set my transform thus:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Entities"
     connectionString="What a nice connection string!"
     xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
     xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I have also tried the `Replace` transform as follows but that doesn't work either:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Entities"
    connectionString="What a nice connection string!"
         xdt:Transform="Replace"
         xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

But I still get a format exception in Entity Framework when my `DbContext` object tries to initialize itself using my connection string.

**2. App Settings**

My `web.config` has the following app settings:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Nice" value="true" />
    <add key="NotNice" value="true" />

    <!-- I want only this one's value to change in my web.local.config -->
    <add key="foo" value ="I am a foo." />
</appSettings>
```

I would like to change just the value of the app setting whose key is `foo` so that my `appSettings` in my `web.local.config` looks as follows:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Nice" value="true" />
    <add key="NotNice" value="true" />

    <!-- I want only this one's value to change in my web.local.config -->
    <add key="foo" value ="Are you also a foo?" />
</appSettings>
```

My presently applied transform looks like so:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value = "Are you also a foo?"
     xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)"
     xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
</appSettings>
```

I have also tried the `Replace` transform as follows but that doesn't work either:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="foo" value = "Are you also a foo?"
  xdt:Transform="Replace"
  xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
</appSettings>
```

But when I read the key `foo` from my `appSettings` when I run my **Local** configuration in debug mode, the code still reads the old value `"I am a foo."`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use "Preview Transform" feature? 
[image]

Also, check your project file to see if there are lines similar to these:

[image]

Please see [SlowCheta Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms) page for additional info.